how to connect nativescript angular mobile apps to firebase
connecting nativescript angular app to firebase
im trying to connect my nativesript mobile app to firebase new verions but im failing to connect it i was using outdated tuttorials. I want to ask on how can i connect the two. I am currently using angular 17

Could you clarify what  means? Is there a specific error code? Is there any evidence on the Firebase side of your attempted connections? Could you please post an excerpt of your Angular code that you're using to attempt to connect? If the tutorial is publicly available, you could post a link to it too.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
